# Should suspensions on parent sites follow through to meta sites?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, per-site-meta

If a user is suspended on the main site, should that suspension carry over to the meta site?

For example, vgv8 is [here asking about their suspension on SF and SU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62755/why-was-i-banned-in-su-msu-sf-msf-so-again). These questions should be asked on the MSF/MSU but they can't, because they're also suspended from there.

Surely a suspension should only affect the parent site, as the meta sites are generally a much smaller community of core users where the suspended user may wish to (politely of course) request feedback, etc from their peers.

To me it seems a bit like shoving them in a black hole without giving them an outlet to [claim their innocence](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/765/can-we-just-get-rid-of-vgv8) (please note, MSO is *not* really a viable alternative, as this site is made up of peers from all over the stack exchange network, and not everyone from the individual meta sites hangs out here).

If they abuse this right however, then of course they should also be able to be suspended from the meta site.

Comment: Did you read his comment on your answer yet?

Comment: @Benjol - I did, but to be fair although it's his situation that has brought this to light, it doesn't *just* apply to him, it applies to every user that gets suspended from this point forward as well.

Comment: There are a few users in whose cases I'm for whichever rule gets them out as far away, as completely, and for as long as possible. vgv8 is one of them. Still, Kudos for demanding fair treatment even if the person in question has not been nice to you at all.

Comment: @Pekka - now I know how a sitting judge must feel. As much as you dislike the person their human rights have to come first :(

Answer (score 2):

No, I think you're right.

However, in vgv8's case, he's managed to insult/annoy enough people that my feeling is that people are starting to react slightly irrationally.

I think the only 'solution' with people like that is to get them in a 'one to one' (in chat for example), to really try to ascertain where they are on the sliding scale between 'deliberate troll' and 'difficult personality/language barrier'.  (Not that I'm aware of that ever having been done successfully)

Answer (score 2):

This is really the sort of thing that should be handled in a direct email to the team, via the address conveniently provided at the bottom of every web page we serve.

Therefore, extending a parent site ban to the child meta site is correct.

Comment: Good point, I'll try to remember suggesting that the next time.

Comment: Fair enough. However I think it's a bit sly to have [this conversation](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/765/can-we-just-get-rid-of-vgv8) effectively right infront of the user without them being able to add anything to the discussion. Admittedly vgv8 is a poor example as I doubt anything constructive would come of it, but I know if I saw that written about me while I was in the sinbin and I couldn't respond you wouldn't ever see me again.